# Merge json files on a "primary key" using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have two files containing json arrays like so

**file1.json**

```
[
  {
    "classid":"abc",
    "name":"Alex"
  },
  {
    "classid":"abc",
    "name":"Bob"
  }
]
```

**file2.json**

```
[
  {
    "classid":"abc",
    "classname":"math"
  }
]
```

I'd like to combine these two files on "classid".
Desired **output.json**

```
[
  {
    "classid":"abc",
    "name":"Alex",
    "classname":"math
  },
  {
    "classid":"abc",
    "name":"Bob",
    "classname":"math
  }
]
```

I tried
`> jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . *= $item)' file1.json file2.json` 
but I see a `jq: error (at file1.json:10): object ({}) and array ([{"classid...) cannot be multiplied`

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have jq 1.6, just use `JOIN` with an `INDEX`:

```bash
jq '[JOIN(INDEX(input[]; .classid); .[]; .classid; add)]' file1.json file2.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "classid": "abc",
    "name": "Alex",
    "classname": "math"
  },
  {
    "classid": "abc",
    "name": "Bob",
    "classname": "math"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Vi7SE3esRme)

Comment: This worked beautifully.

Comment: As a follow up, how would I modify this if they keyNames were different? For example, "class-id" in file1.json and "classId" in file2.json?

Comment: @drfrag01 I have used `.classid` twice. Once as parameter for `INDEX` to reference the primary key in the second array, and once as parameter for `JOIN` to reference the primary key in the first array. Change them as needed.